# How to apply GPU acceleration for huge for loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, gpu

I have a source code following :

```
int func_1(int a)
{
    /*
        do something
    */
}
int func_2(int b)
{
    /*
        do something
    */
}
int main(){
    N=1000000000000;
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 0; i< N; i++)
    {
        int value_1;
        value_1 = func_1(i);
        value_2 = func_2(value_1);
        v.push_back(value_2);
    }
}
```

Which is pretty slow because of the huge `N`, so I am using multithread method to speed them up like below, by simply chunk them into several parts and run them simultaneously.

```
void func_3(int s,int e)
{

    for (int i = s; i< e; i++)
    {
        int value_1;
        value_1 = func_1(i);
        value_2 = func_2(value_1);
        v.push_back(value_2);
    }

}
int main()
{
    int Thread_num=12;
    int firstone=0;
    int N = 1000000000000;
    int chunk = (N-firstone+(Thread_num-1))/Thread_num;
    std::thread t[Thread_num];         
    for(int i=0;i<Thread_num;i++)
    {
      int s =firstone+i*chunk;
      int e = (s+chunk) < N ? (s+chunk) : N;

      t[i]=std::thread(func_3,s,e);          
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Thread_num; ++i)
    {
      t[i].join();
    }
}
```

They can be speed up like 5 times, but it is still not fast enough.
So I am wondering can I use GPU acceleration to speed them up more, openCL, CUDA or something else which one will be more suitable for this situation? I am new about GPU, and there is not too many examples for C++. Does anyone have that experience? Like how to assign same task to GPU's cores.
Appreciated for any help.

Comment: can you fit 1000000000000 ints into your memory?

Comment: This question is a bit broad for this site - [here](http://www.nvidia.com/docs/io/116711/sc11-cuda-c-basics.pdf) is a guide to some of the basics, but porting CPU code to GPU code is a task that you need to do yourself.

Comment: BTW, multithreading does not guarantee simultaneous execution.  The operating system is in charge of delegating chunks of execution to various processors and cores.  There is a possibility that the OS swaps your threads with only one core.

Comment: I agree with @user2717954: With 32-bit ints that would be 3.6 TiB. On what system are you running this? GPU acceleration won't help swapping, a SSD RAID 0 array might :)

Comment: Before you move to the GPU, have you tried optimizing your code?  Reducing function calls, organizing your data to be cache friendly, using less variable, applying `const` correctly, etc.  Profile to find out where the time is spent and optimize that code.

Comment: @user2717954 N is just for example, but thanks for that knowledge :)and the sever has 14 cores, so that why I use 12 threads.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews, I understand they do not execute simultaneously,  just a principle idea :)

Comment: @R_Kapp thank you for that useful guide:)